# Does GRUB actually install an MBR?

Tags: grub2

I’m wondering if I need to use some other utility to actually write the MBR to disk, or if GRUB writes an actual MBR to disk?

The wording in the GRUB2 documentation is not entirely clear on the point.

Comment: If it's needed it would be created